# How to change the width of an html page inserted through iframe to fit the page width?

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I am using iframe to use an html page as header in another html page. The source header width does not fit the screen. Is there any way I can use to make it fit the screen?

Comment: Why are you using an iframe for this? What is the source? A different website?

Comment: yes the other page is not on the same server

Comment: do you have access to the other server?

Comment: no, i am using a url to access that page like "http://www.mypage.com/1.html"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){
      window.setInterval(resizeIframeHeader, 2000);
   });

  var pastHeight = 0;

  function resizeIframeHeader() {
  var currentHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
  var currentWidth = document.body.scrollWidth;
  if (currentHeight != pastHeight){
   pastHeight = currentHeight;
   parent.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight, '*');
  }
 if (currentWidth != pastWidth){
   pastHeight = currentWidth ;
   parent.postMessage(document.body.scrollWidth, '*');
  }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle for your page: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Bamb/)

```
<body>
Your page content
</body>
```